# The sequence $\{S(f,P^t_n)\}$ converges to $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ ( Proof with the traditional definition )

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

Theorem :

> Assume that $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is Riemann-integrable and
>   $\{P_n^t\}$ is a sequence of labeled partitionings such that
>   $\{||P_n^t||\}$ converges to $0$. Then the sequence $\{S(f,P^t_n)\}$
>   converges to $\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

My idea to prove this :

First we show that $\{S(f,P^t_n)\}$ is Cauchy . We conclude that its convergent and then we use the definition of Riemann-integration.  The problem is i can't write my idea... I'm stuck at proving $\{S(f,P^t_n)\}$ is Cauchy.

Note 1 : **My definition of integration is the traditional definition which Riemann introduced.**

Note 2 : $S(f,P^t_n)$ means the Riemann summation of $f$ with respect to the labeled partitioning $P^t_n$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This follows immediately from the Riemann's definition. Just apply the definition. No need to think about Cauchy sequence.